# How to define same MongoClient for local and docker application?

Tags: python, mongodb, docker, pymongo

In order to communicate with MongoDB from Flask, I use the following code to define the connection :

```
CLIENT = pymongo.MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017/')
```

Everything works fine but once I'm trying to deploy my application on Docker I get the following error:

```
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: localhost:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

To solve this problem, I can replace the previous code by:

```
import os
client = MongoClient(os.environ['DB_PORT_27017_TCP_ADDR'],27017)
```

But then it only works on Docker and not on my local machine.
How can I define the connection in order to make it work on both Docker and my local machine ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify that if `DB_PORT_27017_TCP_ADDR` environment variable is present, use that; else use `localhost` using something like this:

```
import os
client = MongoClient(os.environ.get('DB_PORT_27017_TCP_ADDR') or 'localhost', 27017)
```